# conditional probability

Tags: statistics

I'm having difficulty with this question.

In a remote tropical region, there is a direct road from A to B but it is impassable about 50% of the 
time due to rain. An alternative route passes through a third location C. Suppose the road from A to 
C is passable 75% of the time, while the road from C to B is passable 70% of the time. Also, from 
past experience, if the road from A to C is passable, then the road from C to B is passable 80% of 
the time, and if the route from A to C to B is passable, then the direct route from A to B also has an 
80% chance of being passable.

a) State the information given in the question in probability notation.

b) What is the probability a traveller can get from A to B?

c) A traveller journeys from A to C and stays overnight. During the night, rain makes the road 
from A to C impassable. What is the probability the traveller can still get from C to B?

I know I'm getting a) wrong because my answer for b) is greater than 1

Could you please help me?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?  Then it may be easier for someone to make helpful suggestions.

Comment: I'm trying to use conditional probability notations. I get 0.525 for going from A to C and C to B and 0.8 for going from A to C to B and A to B. I think I need to add them for b) but that's greater than 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some thoughts to help you with part (b).

Using $XY$ to mean the direct road from $X$ to $Y$ is passable:

$P(AC \cap CB)=P(AC)P(CB | AC)=(.75)(.8)=.6$

$P((AC\cap CB) \cap (AB))=P(AC\cap CB)P(AB|AC\cap CB)=(.6)(.8)=.48$

To finish off part (b), you want

$P(AB\cup (AC\cap CB))=P(AB)+P(AC\cap CB)-P(AB\cap(AC\cap CB))$